# Unable to draw polylines on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am trying render a polyline dynamically on my page.Here is my javascript function which intends to do so:

```
function decodePath(){
var pathArray=[];
window.alert(("here!!!"));
pathArray=[
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262),
    new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292),
    new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.75737)
];

var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
path: pathArray,
strokeColor: '#FF0000',
strokeOpacity: 1.0,
strokeWeight: 2
});
poly = new google.maps.Polyline(flightPath);
poly.setMap(map);
}
```

The button with which the above function is attached is:

```
<input type="button" onclick="decodePath();" value="Decode Path"/>
```

And the div where map is rendered is:

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

Here is how I initialize:

```
function initialize() {
  var rendererOptions = {
    draggable: true
  };    

  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom:7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: chicago
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I have studied the google map apis https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/,https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference and particularly what I am trying is based on [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple) example. Only I want to add the polylines dynamically. So why is the path not getting displayed on the map?

Comment: [Your code works](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_Polyline_onClick.html) for me.  What do you mean when you say the "path not rendering"?

Comment: @geocodezip your code is not the same as mine.For e.g. the line:<script src="http://www.google-analytics.com/urchin.js" type="text/javascript"> .And as regarding the "path not rendering" I have edited my question. Anyways thanks for your reply!! :)

Comment: That is an analytics tracker, has no effect on the operation of the page...  Is your map displaying?  Does your map have a size (somewhere outside of your posted code)? Is it centering on the polyline? What browser(s) are you using? There are no errors in the posted code.

Comment: 1. You didn't post complete code, but keep saying the working example isn't the same as yours (most of it is) 2. There was no problem with your code, the polyline was rendering, you weren't looking in the right place on the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not centering the map on the polyline, so you can't see it.  Add the code below to your "DecodePath" function to center the map on the polyline.

```
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i=0; i<pathArray.length;i++){
    bounds.extend(pathArray[i]);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
```